# Angular dev/debug mode save main.js file on disk

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Can I set in my angular app, in debug/dev mode... When I'm running my app on my local machine through **ng serve** command, the main.js file write on disk/folder? Which generates in memory but I need it on disk so I can point and interject that file in another browser for debugging.

Comment: What do you mean by injecting it to another browser for debugging? You can debug in as many browsers as you want because the webpack dev server that is used underneath is serving it.

Comment: Like if I have file in folder I can set its path in fiddler's autoresponder: like in this article it is mentioned that javascript from local folder is intersected in autoresponder for development
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/streamline-javascript-development-fiddler-autoresponder